# How to calculate the hash code of a string by hand?

Tags: java, hash

I was wondering how to calculate the hash code for a given string by hand. I understand that in Java, you can do something like:

```
String me = "What you say what you say what?";  
long whatever = me.hashCode();
```

That's all good and dandy, but I was wondering how to do it by hand. I know the given formula for calculating the hash code of a string is something like:

```
S0 X 31 ^ (n-1) + S1 X 31 ^ (n-2) + .... + S(n-2) X 31 + S(n-1)
```

Where S indicates the character in the string, and n is the length of the string. Using 16 bit unicode then, the first character from string me would be computed as:

```
87 X (31 ^ 34)
```

However, that creates an insanely large number. I can't imagine adding all the characters together like that. So, in order to calculate the lowest-order 32 bits result then, what would I do? Long whatever from above equals -957986661 and I'm not how to calculate that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at the source code of `java.lang.String`.

```
/**
 * Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a
 * <code>String</code> object is computed as
 * <blockquote><pre>
 * s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
 * </pre></blockquote>
 * using <code>int</code> arithmetic, where <code>s[i]</code> is the
 * <i>i</i>th character of the string, <code>n</code> is the length of
 * the string, and <code>^</code> indicates exponentiation.
 * (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)
 *
 * @return  a hash code value for this object.
 */
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;
    int len = count;
    if (h == 0 && len > 0) {
        int off = offset;
        char val[] = value;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            h = 31*h + val[off++];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: I get the basic idea (I can compute small strings) but when the string gets large I'm unsure as to what to do.

Comment: @user458346, the size of the string isn't important.  This is the values of using a loop, it doesn't matter how long the loop is, it does get any more complicated.

Comment: where is offset been initiated?

Answer (score 7):

Most hash functions of this sort calculate the hash value [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) some large number (e.g. a large prime). This avoids overflows and keeps the range of values returned by the function within a specified range. But this also means an infinite range of input values will get a hash value from a finite set of possible values (i.e. [0,modulus)), hence the problem of hash collisions.

In this case, the code would look something like this:

```
   public int hash(String x){
        int hashcode=0;
        int MOD=10007;
        int shift=29;
        for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++){
            hashcode=((shift*hashcode)%MOD+x.charAt(i))%MOD;
        }
        return hashcode; 
    }
```

Exercise for the reader:

See the code for the `hashCode` function for java.util.String. Can you see why it does not use a modulus explicitly?

Comment: I can't see... Could You explain it?

Comment: @jjczopek: Notice that `x%2^n = x&(2^n-1)`. So if you did arithmetic modulo 2^n, you just need to keep the last n bits of your value, discarding any higher bits. Now think what happens when you just use an `int` to represent your value. Any arithmetic you do will result in only the last 32 bits being left over. Voila, you have arithmetic modulo 2^32.

Comment: Right. How did you not see that jjczopek >_<.

Answer (score 2):

The following statements will find the string hashCode

```
String str="Hi";

int a = str.hashCode();//returns 2337
```

Let's check how exactly its calculated

HashCode = s[0]*31(n-1) + s[1]*31(n-2) + .. s(n-2)

As we all know that the character at position 0 is H, Character at position 1 is i, and the string length is 2.

==> H*31(2-1) + i*31(2-2)

As we all know that, ASCII code of H is 72, and i is 105. It means,

==> 72 * 31 + 105 * 1 (Anything Power 0 is 1)

==> 2232 + 105 = 2337

Source: https://www.tutorialgateway.org/find-string-hashcode-in-java/